# How to apply Vuejs functionality to items loaded via AJAX

Tags: vuejs2

As titles suggest, I load some items via ajax, each item has a button with "v-on:click" event, but vuejs2 on click cannot be utilised.

Example of what ajax returns:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" v-on:click="selectItem(10)">Select</button>
```

How can I refresh cache/dom (not sure on how to refer to it) so that I can utilise "v-on:click" and other events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it only for a whole component level. Read the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components)